# Expression Property by string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, expression-trees, hotchocolate

I haven't worked with expressions that much, I am trying to reference an Expression property by string name but I cam getting this error:

> c# The member expression must specify a property or method that is
> public and that belongs to the type Soly.Models.Profile (Parameter
> 'expression')

```
public class ProfileFilterType : FilterInputType<Profile> {
        protected override void Configure(
        IFilterInputTypeDescriptor<Profile> descriptor) {
            descriptor.BindFieldsExplicitly();

            descriptor.Field(f => Build<IFilterInputTypeDescriptor<Profile>, string>("firstName"));
        }

        public static Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> Build<TClass, TProperty>(string fieldName) {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TClass));
            var field = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, fieldName);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TClass, TProperty>>(field, param);
        }
    }
```

descriptor.field signature:

```
IFilterFieldDescriptor Field<TField>(Expression<Func<T, TField>> propertyOrMember);
```

I am trying to iterate over the Profile properties with reflection and add a field descriptor for each in HotChocolate GraphQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `descriptor.Field(f => Build<IFilterInputTypeDescriptor<Profile>, string>("firstName"));` to:

```cs
descriptor.Field(Build<Profile, string>("firstName"));
```

Otherwise your are creating an expression with following type `Expression<Func<Profile, Expression<Func<IFilterInputTypeDescriptor<Profile>,string>>>>` which is definitely not what is expected.

P.S.

Not sure, but should not something like `descriptor.Field("firstName");` or `descriptor.Field(p => p.firstName);` just work without need to manually handle expression trees?

Comment: Thank you! that works. My issue with descriptor.Field("firstName") is that GraphQL errors with "For the field FirstName of type ProfileFilterInput was no handler found."
descriptor.Field(p => p.firstName); wont work for me because i am attempting to make something a bit more dynamic for all of my different queries

Comment: I would prefer to use descriptor.Field("firstName") but i just don't understand the error. I do have a bounty started here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74417023/how-to-set-a-dummy-filter-handler-for-an-extending-field-in-hotchocolate-12-grap for an unrelated use-case